# Calculating the largest out of multiple averages - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, Which contains a number of CD Entrys, complete with Names, Price and Genre. I am trying to return the average price by genre, So the average price of "Rock", "Pop", "Alternative Rock", "Electronica", & "Electro House". After then I am then trying to have it automatically display the Genre with the highest average price.

the table is called "CD" then the table columns are CD.ID, CD.Title, CD.Price & CD.Genre

I also have already tried using this method shown below.. Which is currently only trying to establish the different averages for 3 of the genres..

```
SELECT ((SELECT AVG(cdPrice) FROM CD
        WHERE
        CD.Genre = 'Rock') as Rock,
       (SELECT AVG(cdPrice) FROM CD
        WHERE
        CD.Genre = 'Pop') as Pop,
       (SELECT AVG(cdPrice) FROM CD
        WHERE
        CD.Genre = 'Electro') as Electro);
```

However I might be missing something with this method, as I am not overly familiar with the "as" command and its correct usage.

Comment: What DBMS? Sql Server?

Comment: Im using PHP My Admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows are (almost) always easier than columns. So what you want to do first is get the `AVG` price for each genre:

```
SELECT
    AVG(CdPrice) as Price, Genre
FROM CD
GROUP BY Genre
```

The second part is to filter to just the one with the highest `AVG(CdPrice)`. There's a couple of different options here, and it somewhat depends on your requirements What happens if two genres have an equivalent price? Do you want both or random? A simple way for the latter is just order the set and then select the first row:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
    AVG(CdPrice) as Price, Genre
FROM CD
GROUP BY Genre
ORDER BY
    Price DESC
```

If you want both rows in the case of ties, you could first find the max of the set, and then do a self-join to find any matches:

```
SELECT Price, Genre
FROM (
   --First table is our avg price per genre
   SELECT AVG(CdPrice) as Price, Genre FROM CD GROUP BY Genre
) as Avg
JOIN (
   --Second table is the maximum avg price
   SELECT MAX(Price) FROM (
       SELECT AVG(CdPrice) as Price FROM CD GROUP BY Genre
   ) as Avg2
) as Max ON
   --Join on price to find genres that have the maximum price
   Avg.Price = Max.Price
```

Or, you could take advantage of the `HAVING` clause to write that (arguably) a little cleaner:

```
SELECT AVG(CdPrice) as Price, Genre
FROM CD
GROUP BY Genre
HAVING AVG(CdPrice) = (
  SELECT MAX(Price) FROM (SELECT AVG(CdPrice) as Price FROM CD GROUP BY Genre) A
)
```

Comment: This is causing a syntax error, I understand what you are trying to do however it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: You need to add a subselect.

Comment: @TyKitsune - if you're using mySQL, then use LIMIT 1 at end of query instead of TOP(1).

Answer (score 1):

Going to assume that you're using MySQL since you mentioned PHP:

Similar to Mark's answer:

```
select * from (
  SELECT AVG(CdPrice) as Price, Genre
  FROM CD GROUP BY Genre
)averages
order by Price desc
limit 1;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/852cd/1